# Can we edit PFX file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, digital-signature, pfx

I want to customize my .pfx file to include the name of chairpersons of the company along with company name as the companies that are providing the pfx file will issue it with company name only not for individuals.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, We can't edit this file. You can create new file with the same information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but can I use .cer file to sign the pdf using asp.net.

Comment: Your mean is: you can use pfx file after editing to sign the pdf? Because you can not use .cer file to sign (.cer file contains only cer info and public key), beside we need private key to sign data or file.